# Applying a projector or a general nonunitary gate in the middle of a circuit using qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

Is there a way to implement a projector gate in a middle of a circuit?. For instance, assuming I have a Bell state $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$, I'd like to apply a projector on the first qubit onto state $|1\rangle$ (operator $|1\rangle\langle 1|$). Meaning that I will be left with $|1\rangle|1\rangle$.Is it possible to do such thing in the middle, and then apply the rest circuit? Also, is there a way to apply a general nonunitary gate without performing real measurements or qasm, only statevector.

Comment: Would that answer your question? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13725/how-to-code-a-projector-operator-in-qiskit