# Non-unitary projection on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to implement a gate that does a non-unitary projection $|0\rangle\langle0|$ on Qiskit, but apparently I can't because only unitaries are allowed. Is there a work around? Simulating such a projection is necessary for the type of work I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot create a non-unitary quantum gate. Unitarity is a necessary condition, and the only constraint on what makes a valid quantum gate. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15805/13991

Comment: @ryanhill1 isn't there a way to perform this operation on a qubit without using a gate?

Comment: There should be. Maybe this could help? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13797/13991

Comment: Here I used Stinespring dilation to simulate quantum channels: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356206180_Witnessing_the_communication_advantage_of_the_Indefinite_Causal_Orders_on_IBM_Quantum_framework

Comment: Somewhat related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/implement-a-projection-operator-as-a-quantum-circuit

Answer (score 2):

It is true that quantum gates must be unitary. However, there is a trick for encoding non-unitary matrices in quantum circuits, called block encoding. See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29732/doing-non-unitary-operations-on-quantum-computer/29795#29795) to a similar question. There are a number of papers and software implementations, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00081) is a recent one I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to do implement a gate that does a non-unitary projection |0><0|...

Other than measurement, quantum computers have to operate reversibly, which means reversible gate operators have to be unitary.

But the projector $P_0 = |0\rangle\langle 0|$
is not unitary since
$$
P_0 P_0^\dagger = P_0^\dagger P_0 = P_0 \neq 1\;.
$$

Thus $P_0$ is not a reversible quantum computing gate, since such gates are necessarily unitary.

---

Your $P_0$ should rather be referred to as a "measurement" operator, since it is a [measurement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Projective_measurement), or more specifically a "projective measurement" operator.

---

How to implement such a projector in qiskit has already been discussed on this forum: [here is a link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13725/how-to-code-a-projector-operator-in-qiskit).

Comment: Thanks! However, since there will also be other gates and qubits, isn’t there a way that works without using the statevector and evolve(), so that I can work directly on the single qubits?

Comment: Especially when using real devices.